# SQL syntax error edit post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

getting :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's Creed III', description='The plot is set in a fictional
>   history of real ' at line 2

when trying to edit posts on a database.

heres my display and edit php:

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
                // while looping thru each record…
            // output each field anyway you like

            $title =  $row['title'] ;
            $description = $row['description'];
            $year = $row['year'];
            $rating = $row['rating'];
            $genre = $row['genre'];
            $filename =  $row['filename'];
            $imageid = $row['imageid'];

            include '../modules/edit_display.html';
        }



        // STEP 2: IF Update button is pressed , THEN UPDATE DB with the changes posted
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
            $thisTitle = $_POST['title'];
            $thisDescription = $_POST['description'];
            $thisYear = $POST['year'];
            $thisRating = $POST['rating'];
            $thisGenre = $POST['genre'];
            $thisNewFilename =  basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
            $thisOneToEdit = $_POST['imageid'];
            $thisfilename = $_POST['filename'];



            if ($thisNewFilename == ""){
                $thisNewFilename = $thisfilename ;
            } else {
                uploadImage();
                createThumb($thisNewFilename , 120, "../uploads/thumbs120/");
            }



            $sql = "UPDATE gallery SET
                    title='$thisTitle',
                    description='$thisDescription',
                    year='$thisYear',
                    rating='$thisRating',
                    genre='$thisGenre',
                    filename='$thisNewFilename'

                 WHERE 

                    imageid= $thisOneToEdit";

                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());



        }
```

Comment: What is the `title` that you try to insert? This issue may about `single quote` in title.

Comment: replace year with ``year``

Answer (score 3):

You're suffering from an imminent dose of SQL Injection due to using a dangerous user input model.

When you type "Assassin's Creed III" in the `title` field, that gets placed in single quotes in the `UPDATE` statement in your code (via the `$_POST['title']` variable):

```
'Assassin's Creed III'
```

The problem there is that MySQL sees it as `'Assassin'`, followed by `s Creed III'`. It doesn't know what to do with the latter.

Of course, this becomes a HUGE problem if someone types in *valid* SQL at that point, but not what you expected. Have a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) or any of several other advices on avoiding SQL Injection.

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error here. Use `$_POST` instead of `$POST`.

**Replace**

```
 $thisYear = $POST['year'];
 $thisRating = $POST['rating'];
 $thisGenre = $POST['genre'];
```

**With**

```
 $thisYear = $_POST['year'];
 $thisRating = $_POST['rating'];
 $thisGenre = $_POST['genre'];
```

Answer (score 2):

i have seen you are adding `'` into database so you need to escape it using `addslashes()`

```
addslashes($thisTitle)
```

Comment: I thing it must be typo so i am adding this into comment....replace `$POST` to `$_POST`

Comment: I think this issue happened around single quote +1

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape your input like

```
$thisDescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
```

do this for all input that contains quotation marks etc..

NOTE: mysql will soon be gone so its advised to write new code using mysqli instead

Answer (score 1):

You have alot of issues in your script.

1. You're trying to add `'` character to database, you need to escape it properly with `addslashes`.
2. You're vulnerable to `SQL Injection`. Escape it properly with `mysql_real_escape_string`, or even better, use `PDO`.
3. Third, it is `$_POST`, not `$POST`. You're using it wrong in some areas.
4. Add quotes to `$thisOneToEdit` in query.

The error is causing because you're trying to add `Assasin's Creed III` string to database. The single quote breaks your query and creates a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Do a addslashes() on the values that might contain single or double quotes like below before using them in query

```
$thisTitle = addslashes($_POST['title']);
```